# Rate time of ROS code

Tags: ros, gazebo, time, rate, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, is there a way to see how much time my code is taking to run? I don't mean elapsed time but the rate it is working. For example, I have three topics being published and one subscriber and I want to know how the rate at which they are being published.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283530/rate-time-of-ros-code/) by [JuanTelo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32449/juantelo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2018-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use **rqt_graph** to find out the frequency at which messages are being published to your topics. First enable statistics with the following command:

```
rosparam set enable_statistics true
```

Then execute **rqt_graph** as described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_graph).

I'm not quite sure what time you're trying to measure when you say "how much time it takes for the topics to be published" if you don't mean elapsed time. can you clarify this.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JuanTelo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32449/juantelo/) on 2018-02-23**:
You're right, sorry for not being clear in the question, I've edited and will try your answer

**Comment by [JuanTelo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32449/juantelo/) on 2018-02-23**:
Should I write that command in the command line? while rqt is open? because I tried it and still the same, nothing has appeared

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-02-23**:
While your code is running open a new terminal and enter the first command I described. Then on the next line start rqt_graph. This should show a graph of all the nodes, which topics they're publishing and the frequency at which they're being published.